how can i vertically position widgets with pygame_menu?
i have been trying to move a button widget to the top left of the screen, but i am unable to figure out how.
at first i simply tried to fix the issue with set_absolute_position, set_position, and then directly inside of add.button. when that did not work, i googled it, spent 30 minutes on a site i found and figured out how to position them horizontally. i then spent 2 more hours scanning every bit of all the websites i found to find a way to put the widget at the top, but nothing worked and now i'm fully out of ideas to try.
one of the websites i tried was https://pygame-menu.readthedocs.io/en/4.2.4/_source/add_widgets.html, and i also checked the suggested articles.
the closest i got was this:
import pygame
import pygame_menu
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1370, 710))
class firstsettlement:
    def tutorial(self):
        menu.add_text_input("placeholder text")
    def menu(self):
        menu = pygame_menu.Menu('', 1370, 710, theme=pygame_menu.themes.THEME_DARK)
        tutorialbutton = menu.add.button('Tutorial', lambda: self.tutorial(), align=pygame_menu.locals.ALIGN_LEFT)
        return menu
    def run(self):
        menu = self.menu()
        while True:
            screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
            menu.mainloop(screen)
settlement = firstsettlement()
settlement.run()

